# Infinite Variance Probability Distribution

Tags: statistics, variance

I have data $\vec{X}=(x_{1}, ..., x_{n})$ with size $N$, sampled from a physical phenomenon. The data takes discrete values in the range $[-N,N]$. As $N$ is increased, the sample variance and fourth order moments explode. I obtained a theoretical result about the problem that implies as $N\rightarrow +\infty$, then $Variance(\vec{X})\rightarrow \infty$. The mean remains finite. If I am not mistaken, this means that as the distribution converges to be continuous, then the variance tends to $+\infty$. I know that a discrete distribution cannot have infinite variance, of course.

The following figure ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Kh6.png)) shows one example sample obtained with $N=100$. The y-axis shows the relative frequencies and the x-axis the value of $\vec{X}$.
This figure shows another sample with a kernel estimate [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RMp8.png).

I am looking for a distribution that could model this type of data, whether in its continuous limit or discrete. Distributions with infinite variance I am aware of are continuous and exhibit some type of power law, which my estimated samples PMF do not appear show.
My question is: Do you know any distributions that could model this type of data?
Please tell me if I am missing any important information. Any reference or hint would be extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Any distribution restricted to $[-N,N]$ is going to have a  variance no greater than $N^2$, so I suppose some people might say the "sample variance" cannot exceed $\frac{n}{n-1}N^2$.  Similarly the fourth moment cannot exceed $N^4$.  So these are not infinite.  But if you are effectively scaling a distribution with $N$ and $N \to \infty$ then these will also head towards infinity, though there will be no limiting distribution.

Comment: Yes, I said that in the text. The title is somewhat misleading, I will change it.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you have provided it is hard to tell which limiting distribution best describes your data. However, e.g. the student's t-distribution with $1<v\leq 2$ degrees of freedom has a finite mean yet inifite variance. Its support is also the whole real line.